# SUMIFS based on name and date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a formula to sum values on cells based on two criteria, date range and name.

Column A contains Date, Column B contains text, Column C Contains Employee Name, 
I need to sum on a different WS values from column E "Qty" based on criteria from column H "Date" and column C "Employee Name", Column D contains Text, Column E contains number (this is the one I need to add up), Column F contains Employee #, Column G contains number and column H contains date. Rows go from 2 to 100.

I've tried VLOOKUP to find "Employee Name" and SUMIFS for date range but I've been unable to combine both formulas for the desired result.

As an example I need to sum "Qty" for Employee "Jones, Mary" during the month of March and come up with result = 5.

Answer (score 0):

With *March 1, 2015* in A1, *Jones, Mary* in B1 and *'different WS'* called Sheet2, try,

```
=sumifs('Sheet2'!E:E, 'Sheet2'!F:F, B1, 'Sheet2'!H:H, ">="&A1, 'Sheet2'!H:H, "<"&EDATE(A1, 1))
```